# Assign resultSet returned from sql adapter to a global variable and its usage

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

This is my JS FILE

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
function wlCommonInit() {

}
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search").click(function(){
    GetMedicine();

    });



});
window.e='';
var univ;
function GetMedicine() {

    var medicine= $("#medicine").val();
    var location=$("#location").val();
    alert(medicine);
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'ATM',
        procedure : 'getMedicineDetails1',
        parameters: [medicine,location]
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : loadFeedsSuccess,
        onFailure : loadFeedsFailure
    });



}
function loadFeedsSuccess(result){

    window.e=result;
    univ=result.invocationResult.resultSet.length;
    WL.Logger.debug("loadsfeedssuccess");
 if (result.invocationResult.resultSet.length>0) 
    {

         var invocationData={
                    adapter : 'ATM',
                    procedure : 'checkCount',
                    parameters: []
            };
         WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{onSuccess:countgreater});

         }
     else 
        {
        loadFeedsFailure1();

        }
}
function countgreater(result){

    if(result.invocationResult.resultSet.length>0)
        {

        alert("entered count greater");
        var c=result.invocationResult.resultSet[0].num;
        if(c>=0)
            {
    invocationData={
            adapter : 'ATM',
            procedure : 'getStoreDetails',
            parameters: [e[c].RegNo]
    };
 WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{onSuccess:displayAgain});
            }
        else
            {
            invocationData2={
                    adapter : 'ATM',
                    procedure : 'deleteQuery',
                    parameters: []
            };
         WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData2);

            }
}
}
```

ADAPTER JS

```
         var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from medicine WHERE Name= ? ");
var selectStatement2 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select LocId from location WHERE LocName= ? ");
     var selectStatement4 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select RegNo from stormedavl     where MedId=? AND Availability=true");
     var selectStatement5 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from store WHERE RegNo=? ");
     var selectStatement6 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select RegNo from stormedavl where LocId=? AND (MedId=? AND Availability=true)");
     var selectStatement7 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("insert into querycheck values (?)");
     var selectStatement8 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from querycheck");
     var selectStatement9 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("update querycheck set num=?");
     var selectStatement10 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("delete from querycheck");
     var selectStatement11 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("insert into alertcheck values(?)");
     var selectStatement12 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from alertcheck");
    var selectStatement13 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("delete from alertcheck");

    function getMedicineDetails1(Name,Location) { 
    var a=getMedicineDetails(Name);
    var MedId=a.resultSet;
    var b=getLocId(Location);
    var LocId=b.resultSet;
    var d,f,g;
    if(a.resultSet.length>0)
        {
            d=getFinal(LocId[0].LocId,MedId[0].MedId);
            e=d.resultSet;
        if(e && e.length>0)
        {

            var len=e.length-1;
            var r=insertQueryCheck((len));
            if(r.updateStatementResult.updateCount>0)
            return d;
        }
        else
            {
             f=WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
                    preparedStatement : selectStatement4,
                    parameters : [MedId[0].MedId]
                }); 
             if(f.resultSet.length>0)
                 {
                 g=f.resultSet;
                 insertQueryCheck(f.resultSet.length);
                 return f;
                 }

                 }
             else
             { 
                 WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
                        preparedStatement : selectStatement11,
                        parameters : [1]
                    });    
                 return f;

             }

            }
    }
    else
        {
        WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement : selectStatement11,
            parameters : [0]
        });
        return a;
        }

    }
    function getMedicineDetails(Name) {    

       return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement : selectStatement,
            parameters : [Name]
        });
    }
    function getLocId(Location) {  
        return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement : selectStatement2,
            parameters : [Location]
        });
    } 
     function getStoreDetails(RegNo) {  
            return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
                preparedStatement : selectStatement5,
                parameters : [RegNo]
            });   



        }
     function insertQueryCheck(Length) {    
               return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
                preparedStatement : selectStatement7,
                parameters : [Length]
            });
        }
        function checkCount()
        {

            return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
                preparedStatement : selectStatement8,
                parameters : []
            });   

        }
function updateCount(len)
    {

        return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement : selectStatement9,
            parameters : [len]
        });   

    }
    function deleteQuery()
    {

        return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement : selectStatement10,
            parameters : []
        });   

    }
```

I want to assign the resultSet returned to loadFeedsuccess in subsequent functions by assigning it to a global variable 'e'. I am unable to do so. When I am reading e[c].RegNo in countgreater function it shows the error unable to read RegNo from undefined. Is there some way out to do so

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace:

`e[c].RegNo`

With:

`e.invocationResult.resultSet[c].RegNo`

If that doesn't work, just add a log statement an figure out the right path to the value you want. For example:

`alert(JSON.stringify(e))`

or

`console.log(JSON.stringify(e))`

or

`WL.Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(e))`

inside the `loadFeedsSuccess` and `countgreater` functions.